# Implement Elo calculation in a single SQL query with SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, common-table-expression, elo

I'm trying to implement an Elo rating calculation in a single SQL query, but can't make it work. I found [an article](https://elliotchance.medium.com/elo-rating-system-implemented-in-single-sql-select-9511bdff6434) on how to do it with Postgres, but I doesn't work with SQLite. Also, my table schema is a little different:

```sql
CREATE TABLE teams (
  name TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)

CREATE TABLE games (
  "winner_team" TEXT REFERENCES teams,
  "loser_team" TEXT REFERENCES teams
)
```

So far I have following code (To simplify the problem, I'm only looking at the winner teams here and just increase the elo by 1 instead of doing the full calculation):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE elo_ratings(current_game_num, team, previous_elo, new_elo) AS (
  -- Initialize all teams with the default elo
  SELECT
    0 AS game_number,
    name,
    1000.0 AS previous_elo,
    1000.0 AS new_elo
  FROM teams

  UNION

  SELECT
    rowid AS game_number,
    winner_team,
    elo_ratings.new_elo as previous_elo,
    elo_ratings.new_elo + 1
  FROM games
  JOIN elo_ratings ON current_game_num == games.rowid - 1
  LIMIT 10000
)
SELECT * 
FROM elo_ratings
```

But with this code, there is one global `elo_rating` instead of a different one for each player.

How can this be completed?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't come up with a pure SQL solution yet, but there is way to implement it using JSON objects as intermediate "table". This might actually even be a nicer solution.

```sql
WITH  RECURSIVE elo_ratings(current_game_num, elo_map, utc) AS (
  SELECT
    0 AS game_number,
    -- Track all elo ratings in a JSON object
    -- (initialized to 1000 here)
    json_group_object(name, 1000) as elo_map,
    '1970-01-01T00:00:00Z'
  FROM teams

  UNION

  SELECT
    rowid AS game_number,
    -- Apply elo rating changes to JSON object
    json_patch(
      json_patch(
        elo_map, 
        json_object(
          winner_team, 
          elo_map->>winner_team + (32 * (1 -
              ((pow(10, elo_map->>winner_team / 400))  /
              (pow(10, elo_map->>winner_team / 400) + pow(10, elo_map->>loser_team / 400)))
            )
          )
        )
      ),
      json_object(
        loser_team,
        elo_map->>loser_team + (32 * (0 -
            ((pow(10, elo_map->>loser_team / 400)) /
            (pow(10, elo_map->>winner_team / 400) + pow(10, elo_map->>loser_team/ 400)))
          )
        )
      )
    ),
    games.utc
  FROM games
  JOIN elo_ratings ON current_game_num == games.rowid - 1
  ORDER BY games.utc
)
SELECT DISTINCT key, value
FROM 
  (SELECT * 
    FROM elo_ratings 
    ORDER BY current_game_num DESC 
    LIMIT 1
  ),
  json_each(elo_map)
ORDER BY value DESC
```